# Using spring wildcards on tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, wildcard

I have a `war` which contains many JARs inside, and most of them have `properties` files inside them. My goal is to load all those `properties` files in spring context, but apparently it doesn't work on tomcat somehow.

```
<bean class="test.NoMessagesPropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <array>
            <value>classpath*:/**/*.properties</value>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Lets say i have module testWebapp which is `<packaging>war</packaging>` so every property file in this module will end up in `<filename>.war/WEB-INF/classes/...`
And i also have testProperty.jar which is placed in `/WEB-INF/lib/` and this jar contains some property files. With configuration above only property files from testWebapp are being loaded. How to config it to get properties files from jars placed in `lib` dir also (ofcourse without need to explicite put every filename in spring context) ?

Current:

`INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@203feeda: defining beans [test.NoMessagesPropertiesFactoryBean#0]; root of factory hierarchy
Dec 05, 2014 3:01:54 PM org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from file [D:\dev\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\webapps\test\WEB-INF\classes\test\testWebapp.properties]`

Expected:

`INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2ac302a0: defining beans [test.NoMessagesPropertiesFactoryBean#0]; root of factory hierarchy
Dec 05, 2014 3:15:28 PM org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from file [D:\dev\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\webapps\test\WEB-INF\classes\test\testWebapp.properties]
Dec 05, 2014 3:15:28 PM org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from class path resource [test2/test2.properties]
Context started`

Comment: Maybe you should try to use "list", not "array"?

Comment: @mkrakhin tried various possibilities - list, array and `<property name="locations" value="classpath*:**/*.properties"/>`. Every one of them works fine when program is run from IntelliJ (as 'main' not as web application), but problem starts when it's packed into war and deployed on tomcat

Comment: Oh. Sure. I see. classpath root is WEB-INF/classes. It doesn't see WEB-INF/lib directory.